# how to sed for pattern before and after match

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I currently am trying to get specific parameters from a url.

My url looks like: `https://private.io/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/redhat/ubi/ubi7/7.8/2020-02-14T222203.548_2868/ubi7-7.8.tar`

I want just `redhat/ubi/ubi7/7.8`

I can get `redhat/ubi/ubi7/7.8/2020-02-14T222203.548_2868/ubi7-7.8.tar` by doing,

`echo https://private.io/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/redhat/ubi/ubi7/7.8/2020-02-14T222203.548_2868/ubi7-7.8.tar | sed 's|.*/container-scan-reports/||'`

Thus I want to remove `/2020-02-14T222203.548_2868/ubi7-7.8.tar`

I also would like to change the `/` to a `-` so that I have `redhat-ubi-ubi7-7.8`

Comment: `sed -E 's|^([^/]*/){6}||;s|(/[^/]*){2}$||;s|/|-|g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

Get the 4 following path elements after `.*/container-scan-reports/` and replace all `/` with `-`:

```
url='https://private.io/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/redhat/ubi/ubi7/7.8/2020-02-14T222203.548_2868/ubi7-7.8.tar'
echo "$url" | sed -E 's|.*/container-scan-reports/(([^/]*/){3}[^/]*).*|\1|;s|/|-|g'
```

Or you could get everything after `.*/container-scan-reports/`, but not the last two path elements:

```
echo "$url" | sed -E 's|.*/container-scan-reports/(.*)/[^/]*/[^/]*|\1|;s|/|-|g'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you know the position in the string you can use `cut`

```
echo "${string}" | cut -d/ -f 7-10 | tr '/' '-'
```

Another way with `sed` is

```
echo "${string}" | sed -E 's#([^/]*/){6}([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).*#\2-\3-\4-\5#'
```